# Windows 10 desktop does not react on icon mouseover in the first minutes of RDP connection

Tags: windows, windows-10, remote-desktop, taskbar, icons

I connect to a Windows 10 PC (the host) over RDP from a Ubuntu Linux machine (the client). On the Linux machine, I mostly use `remmina`, but I experience the same problem with `xfreerdp` as well.

This is the problem: once I log in, when I move the mouse pointer over taskbar icons, they do not react (there is no change in background color of the icon on mouseover); and when nothing happens when I click these icons (which should otherwise start a program). This includes also the Start button.

Same with regular desktop icons - they do not react on mouseover (there is no change in background color of the icon on mouseover); and when I double-click them, no program is started.

Basically, in this state, both the desktop and the taskbar icons are "frozen" and do not react. (In this state, I can run a program via Ctrl-Alt-Delete, starting Task Manager, and then doing File/Run new task from Task Manager)

Then, after some 10-15 minutes, there is a visible "refresh" of the Desktop, and suddenly the taskbar icons and the Desktop icons start working!

So, I was wondering - does anyone know of an actual program/service, that I could restart in Windows 10 once an RDP connection is established, so I can get Taskbar/Desktop icons working immediately, without waiting 10-15 minutes for them to "wake up"?

Comment: Not sure if this would make any difference, but you could try killing and restarting explorer.exe

Comment: When Windows first starts, whether waking from hibernation or cold boot, it performs malware scans that considerably slow the machine. For example, on some dual-boot machines, I find it takes ~5 minutes for the PC to come up to full speed *after showing the desktop* on Windows, whereas on Linux, as soon as the desktop shows, the machine is ready for work. Perhaps that initial scan causes the issue. Run Task Manager to see if a process is using a great deal of CPU or I/O at startup. If so, see if it can be set to lower priority or killed.